# How to close the user browser tab/window in js

Tags: javascript, html

Just to confirm current browser window could never be closed through JS?

Comment: @j08691 can we delete this question? I think the answer is its not doable with js. Above question was asked in 2010. window functions changed since 2017 with security aspects.

Answer (score 1):

So, the `window.close` method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method.

For example, the following script will work:

```js
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
  myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}

function closeWin() {
  myWindow.close();
}
```

You just need to make sure you call `close` on the window that has a `open` called upon previously.

Comment: I want to close the browser window which I gues not doable with js